Stuck in help and support ui
Can someone help me. When i'm proccess instalation. Stuck with this message in the terminal
subquity/errorreporter/1733203807.934005976.install_fail/add_info

Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What are you installing? Ubuntu? A program that runs on Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu? What program? How are you installing? What exact commands/process did you follow? At what point of the process do you see this error?
